# Closing GUI Window Python MAYA

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, maya

Seems to be an issue when trying to close the window.

## Error: invalid syntax

Heres the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def shapeTool ():
ram = 'RenamerWin'
if cmds.window(ram, q = True, exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI(ram)

ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Shape Tool", w=300, h=300)
cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
cmds.separator(h=20)
cmds.text("Welcome to the Shape Creator")
cmds.separator(h=20)


cmds.button(label='Close Window',command="cmds.deleteUI('%s')")


cmds.showWindow(ram)

shapeTool()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed your format :)

```
cmds.button(label='Close Window',command="cmds.deleteUI('%s')" % ram)
```